# Python runtime crashing while reading data from a database into a Polars dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, database, python-polars

I'm currently working on a data engineering project where I have to read data from a database, perform manipulations on it in Python and then write the data to a csv file. I'm using `pyodbc` for database connection and Polars for creating and manipulating dataframes.

EDIT: The database I'm using only supports `pyodbc`, so I can't use any other connector.

This is the code I've written to read in the data:

```
import pyodbc
import polars as pl

con_str = "...."
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(con_str)
curs = cnxn.cursor()

df = pl.read_database(query, curs)
```

But the program keeps crashing every time I run it. I also tried reading data without using Polars, by just using `curs.fetchall()` and `curs.fetchone()`. The program crashed while using `curs.fetchall()`, but works fine when I use `curs.fetchone()`. This leads me to believe that it is a memory related issue, although I don't understand why it happens since Polars should be capable of handling large datasets. How do I resolve this issue ?

Comment: when you say the program keeps crashing - are you getting some error message?

Comment: I get this when I run it on a jupyter notebook in vs code:

'The Kernel crashed while executing code in the current cell or a previous cell. 

Please review the code in the cell(s) to identify a possible cause of the failure.'

And on the vs code terminal, I don't get anything. The execution just stops.

Comment: `.read_database` loads everything into memory. You can pass `iter_batches=True` to batch the data if the engine supports it. A streaming `scan_database` does not exist as of yet: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9091#issuecomment-1721547323